# How to set up the index file of a React application with React-Redux and Apollo-client for user administration to be able to edit context

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Initially before I was looking to add user administration to my index.js file it looked like this and everything functioned as intended.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks"

const renderApp = () => {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
    })

    return (
            ReactDOM.render(
                <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <App />
                    </Provider>
                </ApolloProvider>,
                document.getElementById('root')
            )
    )
}

renderApp()

store.subscribe(() => (
    renderApp()
))
```

Afterwords I made the following changes hoping that I would be able to edit the context to hold the user token so that it could manage the user.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks"
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'

const renderApp = () => {
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    })

    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `berySecret ${token}` : null,
            }
        }
    })
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
    })

    return (
            ReactDOM.render(
                <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <App />
                    </Provider>
                </ApolloProvider>,
                document.getElementById('root')
            )
    )
}

renderApp()

store.subscribe(() => (
    renderApp()
))
```

(IMPORTANT: outside of the index.js file I did not change anything else in the front-end)

After making these changes it seemed as if the front-end React application could no longer reach the back-end. When i tried to make the same Graph QL queries I got the following response object with this error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500.

(NOTE: the back-end works as intended for when i work on it through the Graph QL playground i don`t get any issues.)

> called: true
>
> client: Object { defaultOptions: {}, disableNetworkFetches: false, queryDeduplication: true, … }
>
> data: undefined
>
> error: Error: "Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500"
>
> fetchMore: function ()
>
> loading: false
>
> networkStatus: 8

Comment: compare (with playground) request headers - `berySecret`, are you sure? check it STRICTLY

Comment: should not be `for user authentication` in title ??